# custom formatter for grouptext in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Is there a way I can use `custom formatter` to format the `grouptext` value in jqgrid.

Current Output for `var grouping=new Array("Environment", "System", "IIR","Userlimit","Kernel Parameters");`
[image]
Suppose I have these groups.

```
var grouping=new Array("3Environment", "0System", "4IIR","2Userlimit","1Kernel Parameters");
```

If I sort it in ascending order it should display `System, Kernel, Userlimit, Environment, IIR` i.e., using some kind of custom formatter remove `01234` from 1st character or similar to **sort my groups in some already decided order**.

jqGrid Code

```
$('#compareContent').empty();
        $('<div id="compareParentDiv" width="100%">'+
          '<table id="list2" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"></table>'+
                '<div id="gridpager3"></div></div>')
        .appendTo('#compareContent');

        $("#compareParentDiv").hide();

        var gridDiff = $("#list2");
        gridDiff.jqGrid({
            datastr: compareData,
            datatype: "jsonstring",
            colNames: ['KeyName', 'SubCategory', starheader, header1,'isEqual'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'elementName', index: 'elementName', key: true, width: 120 },
                { name: 'subCategory', index: 'subCategory', width: 1 },
                { name: 'firstValue', index: 'firstValue', width: 310, jsonmap:'attribute.0.firstValue' },
                { name: 'secondValue', index: 'secondValue', width: 310,jsonmap:'attribute.0.secondValue' },
                { name: 'isEqual', index: 'isEqual', width: 1,hidden:true}
            ],
            pager: '#gridpager3',
            rowNum:60,
            scrollOffset:1,
            //viewrecords: true,
            jsonReader: {
                repeatitems: false,
                page: function(){return 1;},
                root: "response"
            },
            //rownumbers: true,

            height: '320',
            autowidth:true,
            grouping: true,

            groupingView: {
                groupField: ['subCategory'],
                groupOrder: ['desc'],
                groupDataSorted : false,
                groupColumnShow: [false],
                //groupCollapse: true,
                groupText: ['<b>{0}</b>']

            },

            loadComplete: function() {
                if (this.p.datatype !== 'local') {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                       gridDiff.trigger('reloadGrid');
                   }, 0);
                } else {
                    $("#compareParentDiv").show();
                }

                var i, names=this.p.groupingView.sortnames[0], l = names.length;
                 data = this.p.data, rows = this.rows, item;


                for (i=0;i<l;i++) {
                    if ($.inArray(names[i],grouping) >= 0) {

                        $(this).jqGrid('groupingToggle',this.id+"ghead_"+i);

                        $(rows.namedItem(this.id+"ghead_"+i)).find("span.ui-icon").click(function(){
                            var len = data.length, iRow;
                            for (iRow=0;iRow<len;iRow++) {
                                item = data[iRow];
                                if (item.isEqual) {
                                    $(rows.namedItem(item._id_)).hide();
                                }
                            }
                        });

                    } else {
                        // hide the grouping row
                        $('#'+this.id+"ghead_"+i).hide();
                    }
                    //console.info($('#'+this.id+"ghead_"+i));
                }

                var i, names=this.p.groupingView.sortnames[0], l = names.length,
                data = this.p.data, rows = this.rows, item; 

                l = data.length;
                for (i=0;i<l;i++) {
                    item = data[i];
                    if (!item.isEqual) {
                        $(rows.namedItem(item._id_))
                            .css({
                                "background-color": "#FFE3EA",
                                "background-image": "none"
                            });
                    } else {
                        $(rows.namedItem(item._id_)).hide();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        gridDiff.jqGrid('navGrid', '#gridpager3', { add: false, edit: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: false });
        gridDiff.jqGrid('navButtonAdd',"#gridpager3",{caption:"Toggle",title:"Toggle Search Toolbar", buttonicon :'ui-icon-pin-s',
            onClickButton:function(){
                gridDiff[0].toggleToolbar();
            } 
        });
        gridDiff.jqGrid('navButtonAdd',"#gridpager3",{caption:"Clear",title:"Clear Search",buttonicon :'ui-icon-refresh',
            onClickButton:function(){
                gridDiff[0].clearToolbar();
            } 
        });
        gridDiff.jqGrid('filterToolbar',
                {stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: 'cn'});
```

**Update**

Or is there a way to use positioning to place each grouped item, if sorting is not an option

**Updated after accepting answer by Oleg**

Page1 
[image: Page1]

Page3
[image: Page3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you have not the problem with the custom formatter of the grouptext

You use `groupingView` having `groupDataSorted: false` so the sorting of the group (in your case `groupField: ['subCategory']` with `groupOrder: ['asc']`) do jqGrid for you. So the standard sorting behavior will be used.

jqGrid supports `sorttype` property of the [colModel](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acolmodel_options) which define how the column should be sorted. If you need custom sorting order you should define `sorttype` property as a function which returns integer or string used **instead of** the cell value from the column. the prototype of the `sorttype` function could be `function(cellValue,rowData)` so it is possible to define the order which not only the cell value of the sorted column will be used but the whole contain of the row inclusive `_id_` property. In you case the usage of the first `cellValue` parameter would be enough.

So to solve you problem you can for example define an array with the order of 'subCategory' values which you need:

```
var orderOfSubCategory = [
    "System", "system", "Kernel", "Kernel Parameters", "Userlimit",
    "Environment", "IIR", "Product"
];
```

and then define `'subCategory'` column as following:

```
{
    name: 'subCategory',
    index: 'subCategory',
    width: 1,
    sorttype: function (value) {
        return $.inArray(value, orderOfSubCategory);
    }
}
```

You should don't forget, that [jQuery.inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) return 0-based index of the item or -1 if the item will be not found in the array. So the values of 'subCategory' which could be not found in the `orderOfSubCategory` array will be placed the first. See [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/AbhishekSimon7.htm) the corresponding demo.

Some other small remarks about your code. You use `new Array(...)` which is bad practice in JavaScript instead of that you should use always `[...]` construct which do the same is shorter and work quickly. Example: `var grouping = ["Environment", "System", "IIR","Userlimit","Kernel Parameters"];`

Another place which is difficult for to read for me is:

```
$('#compareContent').empty();
$('<div id="compareParentDiv" width="100%">'+
  '<table id="list2" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"></table>'+
        '<div id="gridpager3"></div></div>')
    .appendTo('#compareContent');
$("#compareParentDiv").hide();
```

Here you first use `cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"` attributes of the `table` which are unneeded and seconds use `empty()`, `append()` combination instead of one `html()` call. The following code do the same, but it seems me better:

```
$('#compareContent').html(
    '<div id="compareParentDiv" style="display: none" width="100%">' +
    '<table id="list2"></table><div id="gridpager3"></div></div>');
```

Comment: Very nice explanation and approach. Thanks Oleg

Comment: I am having one problem, after I add sorting from your answer, `IIR` goes to next page since `Environment` and others exceed `rowNum:60,` I wanted that when the user sees the grid 1st he is able to all the groupings, if not all then till the height of thr grid all the groupings should appear `height: '320',`. I also want paging, because `Environment` can have more than 100 values.. Any chance I can have such a solution? I added a screen shot

Comment: @Abhishek Simon: If you would place in the data from the first page produced by the server at lease one item from **all** groups and use **server side paging** your new requirements could be implemented. If you don't want to have server side paging I see the usage of `rowNum:1000` as the only way.

Comment: Can't we have some kind of positioning of the groups here ` var i, names=this.p.groupingView.sortnames[0], l = names.length;
                    for (i=0;i<l;i++) {
                        if ($.inArray(names[i],grouping) >= 0) {
                            $(this).jqGrid('groupingToggle',this.id+"ghead_"+i);
                        } else {
                            // hide the grouping row
                            $('#'+this.id+"ghead_"+i).hide();
                        }
                    }`

Comment: @@Abhishek Simon: Sorry, but I don't understand what kind of "positioning" you mean. You should understand, that in case of grouping there are exactly `rowNum` rows on the page. The rows with the data are just *hidden*. So the grouping headers of the rows on the current page could be only shown.

Comment: thanks.. also by positioning I mean.. that System will come on 1st page's 0th location or row likewise, also if you are free please take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939096/hide-grouping-heading-in-jqgrid-if-every-row-inside-it-is-hidden)

Comment: Do you have any link that could give me an idea of server side pagination.. which will help me achieve solution to this question?

Comment: @Abhishek Simon: The server code depends on the language (C#, Java, PHP, ...), technology (ASP.NET MVC, WCF, ...), database access technology (`SqlDataReader`, Entity Framework, LINQ to SQL ...), the database which you use (Microsoft SQL, MySQL, ...) and so on. So it's difficult to recommend you something without additional information.

Comment: Please look at a similar [question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9962931/jqgrid-sort-subgrid-values-based-on-some-key)