# JQGrid: Sort subgrid values based on some key

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid with a subgrid. I want to sort the subgrid so that important details are shown in sorted order inside the subgrid.

Sorted Order: **EBFNUM, VERSION & APPLIEDDATETIME**

Below is a screen shot
[image]

**Optional**: The filter works for `elementName`, `isPresentinXml1` & `isPresentinXml2`. Is there anyway the same filter can work for `name`, `firstValue` & `secondValue` (Subgrid columns)?

Code for grid

```
_starHeader="infa9 windowsss";
_header1="infa9_windowss";
 grid = jQuery("#ebfList");
             grid.jqGrid({
                 datastr : compareEBFData,
                 datatype: 'jsonstring',
                 colNames:['EBF','',_starHeader, _header1],
                 colModel:[
                     {name:'elementName',index:'elementName', width:188},
                     {name:'subCategory',index:'subCategory',hidden:true, width:1},
                     {name:isPresentinXml1,index:isPresentinXml1, width:270, align:'center', formatter: patchPresent},
                     {name:isPresentinXml2,index:isPresentinXml2, width:270, align:'center', formatter: patchPresent}
                 ],
                 pager : '#ebfGridpager',
                 rowNum:60,
                 rowList:[60,120,240],
                 scrollOffset:0,
                 height: 'auto',
                 autowidth:true,
                 viewrecords: false,
                 gridview: true,
                 loadonce:true,

                 jsonReader: {
                    repeatitems: false,
                    page: function() { return 1; },
                     root: "response"
                 },
                 subGrid: true,
                 // define the icons in subgrid
                 subGridOptions: {
                     "plusicon"  : "ui-icon-triangle-1-e",
                     "minusicon" : "ui-icon-triangle-1-s",
                     "openicon"  : "ui-icon-arrowreturn-1-e",
                     //expand all rows on load
                     "expandOnLoad" : false
                 },

                 loadComplete: function() {
                     if (this.p.datatype !== 'local') {
                         setTimeout(function () {
                            grid.trigger('reloadGrid');
                        }, 0);
                     } else {
                        $("#compareEBFDiv").show();                         
                     }
                 },

                 subGridRowExpanded: function(subgrid_id, row_id) {
                    var subgrid_table_id, pager_id, iData = -1;
                     subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id+"_t";
                     $("#"+subgrid_id).html("<table id='"+subgrid_table_id+"' style='overflow-y:auto' class='scroll'></table><div id='"+pager_id+"' class='scroll'></div>");

                     $.each(compareEBFData.response,function(i,item){
                         if(item.id === row_id) {
                             iData = i;
                             return false;
                         }

                     });
                     if (iData == -1) {
                         return; // no data for the subgrid
                     }

                     jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
                         datastr : compareEBFData.response[iData],
                         datatype: 'jsonstring',
                         colNames: ['Name','Value1','Value2'],
                         colModel: [
                             {name:"name",index:"name",width:70},
                             {name:firstValue,index:firstValue,width:100},
                             {name:secondValue,index:secondValue,width:100}
                         ],
                         rowNum:10,
                         //pager: pager_id,
                         sortname: 'name',
                         sortorder: "asc",
                         height: 'auto',
                         autowidth:true,
                         jsonReader: {
                             repeatitems: false,
                             //page: function() { return 1; },
                             root: "attribute"
                         }
                     });

                     jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid('navGrid',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});
                 }
             });

             grid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#ebfGridpager', { search: false, refresh: false });
             grid.jqGrid('navButtonAdd',"#ebfGridpager",{caption:"Toggle",title:"Toggle Search Toolbar", buttonicon :'ui-icon-pin-s',
                onClickButton:function(){
                    grid[0].toggleToolbar();
                } 
             });
             grid.jqGrid('navButtonAdd',"#ebfGridpager",{caption:"Clear",title:"Clear Search",buttonicon :'ui-icon-refresh',
                onClickButton:function(){
                    grid[0].clearToolbar();
                } 
             });
             grid.jqGrid('filterToolbar',
                    {stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: 'cn'});
```

Json response

```
    {
  "response": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "elementName": "EBF262323",
      "category": "Product",
      "subCategory": "EBFINFO",
      "isEqual": false,
      "isPrasentinXml1": true,
      "isPrasentinXml2": true,
      "isPrasentinXml3": false,
      "attribute": [
        {
          "name": "APPLIEDDATETIME",
          "firstValue": "Mon Sep 05 11:12:32 IST 2011",
          "secondValue": "Mon Sep 05 11:12:32 IST 2011"
        },
        {
          "name": "VERSION",
          "firstValue": "9.1.0",
          "secondValue": "9.1.0"
        },
        {
          "name": "EBFNUM",
          "firstValue": "EBF262323",
          "secondValue": "EBF262323"
        }

      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "elementName": "EBF99993",
      "category": "Product",
      "subCategory": "EBFINFO",
      "isEqual": false,
      "isPrasentinXml1": true,
      "isPrasentinXml2": true,
      "isPrasentinXml3": false,
      "attribute": [
        {
          "name": "APPLIEDDATETIME",
          "firstValue": "Mon Sep 09 11:12:32 IST 2012",
          "secondValue": "Mon Sep 09 11:12:32 IST 2012"
        },
        {
          "name": "VERSION",
          "firstValue": "9.1 HF2",
          "secondValue": "9.1 HF2"
        },
        {
          "name": "EBFNUM",
          "firstValue": "EBF99993",
          "secondValue": "EBF99993"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "xls_path": "/files/modifiedServices.xls"
}
```

**UPDATE**

I tried something like below code, inside my inner grid, but has no effect

```
var orderOfEBFSubCategory = [
    "EBFNUM",
    "PRODUCT",
    "VERSION"
];

{name:"name",index:"name",width:70,
                                sorttype: function (value) {
                                    var order = $.inArray(value, orderOfEBFSubCategory);
                                    return order;
                                }},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the approach with the usage of `sorttype` as function is the correct way if you need to implement custom sorting order. The problem is only that you used `datatype: 'jsonstring'` and `datastr` in the subgrid. It's important to understand, that **the data from `datastr` will be interpret as already sorted**. If you have non-sorted data you should use  `datatype: 'local'` instead. The `jsonReader` parameter should be removed in the case. So the code of subgrid should be like

```
jQuery("#" + subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
    data: compareEBFData.response[iData].attribute,
    datatype: 'local',
    gridview: true,
    idPrefix: 's' + row_id + '_',
    colNames: ['Name', 'Value1', 'Value2'],
    colModel: [
        {name: "name", index: "name", width: 70,
            sorttype: function (value) {
                var order = $.inArray(value, orderOfEBFSubCategory);
                return order;
            }},
        {name: firstValue, index: firstValue, width: 100},
        {name: secondValue, index: secondValue, width: 100}
    ],
    rowNum: 10,
    sortname: 'name',
    sortorder: "asc",
    height: 'auto',
    autowidth: true
});
```

where

```
var orderOfEBFSubCategory = [
        "EBFNUM",
        "VERSION",
        "APPLIEDDATETIME"
    ];
```

See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/AbhishekSimon12.htm). It can be that your main problem was just to have just *sorted* items and not *custom sorted* items. In the case you can remove `sorttype` function and you will have alphabetic sorted names in case of usage `datatype: 'local'`.

It's important to mention, that I fixed in your original code one more important problem by adding additional options. First I added `gridview: true` to improve the performance and the second I added `idPrefix: 's' + row_id + '_'` option. You code from the demo don't defined any `id` for the grid rows. So the rows of the main grid has ids: 1, 2, ... The subgrids has also no `id` defined. So If you would be opened the first and the second subgrids in your original grid you had **at least three id duplicates**: in main grid and in all subgrids was the rows with the same ids 1, 2, ... The `idPrefix` can be used to solve the problem. In the fixed grid you can now for example select row in every subgrid and one in the main grid without any conflicts.

Comment: thanks for your answer with a demo. I copied your whole code inside `$(document).ready` to my project, but it is not sorting.. where I might be going wrong?

Comment: @AbhishekSimon: You should examine the page in the debugger: probably some variable like `orderOfEBFSubCategory` are undefined. You can start IE Developer Tools with F12, choose "Script" tab and click "start debugging". You can set breakpoint on the `var order = $.inArray(value, orderOfEBFSubCategory);` line and verify that the `sorttype` will be called on opening of the subgrid. So the subgrig should be sorted. You can repeat the same steps on my demo and with your code. I hope you will find the problem in the way.