# Can not select row in subgrid : Jqgrid

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid, and added one subgrid inside it, which looks like as below,

[image]

As you can see,
Rows with columns having 11 and 13 are main grid rows

And every row has subgrid having interest, 
The Add Record element shows Add Pop up for Subgrid

Here is the code for subgrid looks like,

```
subGridRowExpanded: function(subgrid_id, row_id) {
            var subgrid_table_id, pager_id;
            subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id+"_t";
            pager_id = "p_"+subgrid_table_id;
            $("#"+subgrid_id).html("<table id='"+subgrid_table_id+"' class='scroll'></table><div id='"+pager_id+"' class='scroll'></div>");
            jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
                url:"shops?q=2&ShopID="+row_id,
                datatype: "xml",
                colNames: ['Interest'],
                colModel: [
                    //{name:"Id",index:"ShopID",width:80,editable:false,editoptions:{readonly:false,size:40}}, //Shop ID not required
                    {name:"id",index:"id",editable:true,edittype:"select",editoptions:{dataUrl:'shops?q=3&ShopID='+row_id},editrules:{required:true}}
                ],
                rowNum:10,
                pager: pager_id,
                width: '100%',
                height: '100%',
                scrollOffset: 0,
                sortname: 'num',
                sortorder: "asc",
                height: '100%',
                editurl:'shops?q=5&ShopID='+row_id
            });
            jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid('navGrid',"#"+pager_id,{edit:false,add:true,del:true})
        },
        subGridRowColapsed: function(subgrid_id, row_id) {
            // this function is called before removing the data
            //var subgrid_table_id;
            //subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id+"_t";
            //jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id).remove();
        }
```

Problem is , when there are more than one element in subgrid, i can select that (I use latest version of Chrome) but when there is only single element in subgrid surprisingly I can select it ( if you notice the color difference please see  subgrid element 'Gifts' -selected below row 13 ) and once select that 'Gifts' can be deleted.

**UPDATE:**
In firefox and IE , only first row gets selected from subgrid

Is there something wrong in the code ? why can't i select single element when there are more than one elements in subgrid ?

Appreciate your time, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you have problem with id duplicates. HTML don't allow to use `id` attributes on the same HTML pages with the same values. The values of all `id` attributes **must be unique**. I recommend you to verify that you have the problem by usage of Developer Tools of Chrome/IE or using Firebug. You need just examine the `id` attributes which you have now on `<tr>` elements of grid and subgrids.

On the other side *all rows* (all `<tr>` elements) of jqGrid become an `id` attribute assigned. Typically you have to fill `id` in the server side in the response of `url`. The problem is that one use typically the values from `id` from the database, but you have typically unique `id` only *over one table* of the database and not over all tables on the database. So you can easy have the scenario where multiple jqGrids (or grid with subrird) get rows with id duplicates.

The most easy way to fix the problem is to use `idPrefix` option which was introduced in jqGrid after [my suggestion](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/prefixes-to-rowids/#p18336). The main advantage is that you can continue to use *the original* id values which you have in the database and use `id` attributes in jqGrid which will be unique because of building `id` attributes from the `id` values returned from the server, but with the usage of prefixes. In [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9698470/315935). So I recommend you to use different `idPrefixes` for all subgrids. For example you can use `idPrefix: 's' + row_id + '_'` in subgrid (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9963508/315935) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10247633/315935)).

Comment: Thanks, Yes you are right , actually id's are same for subgrid elements , problem is, i use that id as a primary key , i need to use some combination to uniquely identify each row , i will try this

Comment: @pradeep: If you add `idPrefix` with some value which will be different in every grid and subgrid the problem should be solved.

Comment: Thank you very much !, How can we survive without guys like you :)
Instead of prefix , i modified at server end so that each subgrid row will have unique id